# Unable to Load File in PowerShell Due to Lack of Digital Signature

Tags: file, unsigned

Hello StackOverflow community,

I’m a novice in PowerShell and I’m currently facing an issue that I hope you can help me with. I’m trying to execute a script provided by Microsoft that enlarges the WinRE (Windows Recovery Environment) partition. However, I’ve encountered a problem.

The script is located at C:\1\1.ps1, but it seems that it cannot be loaded. The error message indicates that the file is not digitally signed. Here’s the exact error message:

```
.\1.ps1 : File C:\1\1.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\1\1.ps1 is not digitally signed. You
cannot run this script on the current system.
```

A PowerShell Screenshot of the steps I took
[image]

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` will bypass the check. Looks like the first part of your screenshot shows you set the execution policy to Remote-Signed. You should google this